# store images in database when uploaded from mobile asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, mysql

How it can be implemented that :
Images are uploaded from an mobile app and that images sholud be stored in our database?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing image into database, save image in one particular common path on server and give each image a unique name maybe the 'primaryid (suppose you have image table in your database) + image extension' and save this unique name into the another column of that table.
and whenever you want to fetch image concat the common path and image name from db table and use it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to convert the image into a byte array and store that.  Then, upon retrieval, you'll have to convert the byte array back to an image.  However it's more common to implement a solution as @ganesh suggests.